# 'Be shot' in place of 'to be shot'

Tags: sentence-structure

In a war, You either shoot or **be shot**.

(This sentence is written in the sense of telling a general fact about war, it's not in imperative mood)

One explanation I think is Since Either-or is Correlative conjunction...so the items they are connecting must follow the same grammatical structure.

Here, 'be' is a primary verb and 'Shot' a noun working as a verb complement.

Another reason I guess is  After 'either' we use a plain verb not Infinitive verb....so after 'or' we have to remove 'to' from 'to be shot' in the process of giving passive sense and not using  a passive of Infinitive verb(but it doesn't follow the same grammatical structure theory...as First verb is in active structure and second in passive).

Which of them is correct or they r both wrong?

Comment: It may be worth noting that both "shoot" and "be shot" work as imperative constructions.  If someone tells you that the imperative never takes a subject, don't you believe it.

Comment: Okay.....but what if  'you'is not the subject instead 'he' is the subject....then the sentence, I guess won't be imperative.......and it would be like 'He either shoot or be shot'...... This sentence is lil weird but It's still grammatical and giving sense

Comment: If we trim it down to "In a war, shoot or be shot", it's clearly imperative despite still being a general fact about war.  One alternative clearly in the indicative mode is "you shoot or you get shot".